# how to select in sql twice in a table?

Tags: sql

I have these 2 tables:

`COMPANY` (all company)

| ID | Registration_number |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | 101010 |
| 02 | 202020 |
| 03 | 303030 |

`RECORDS` (all company records)

| ID | Company_id | Number_Rec | Date_Rec | archived |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 01 | 52541 | 02.02.2024 | 0 |
| 02 | 01 | 87559 | 05.05.2023 | 1 |
| 03 | 01 | 65471 | 03.03.2018 | 0 |
| 04 | 02 | 25458 | 01.01.2022 | 1 |
| 05 | 02 | 56448 | 02.02.2017 | 0 |
| 06 | 03 | 65464 | 02.02.2024 | 0 |
| 07 | 03 | 46486 | 04.04.2019 | 0 |

`ID` is unique for each table, and `company.id = records.company_id`.

I want to select all records where `Data_rec = 02.02.2024`, and once again from all `id_company` selected above, I want to select all my records older than 2020 and `records.archived = 0`

The result should be this data set:

| ID | Company_id | Number_Rec | Date_Rec | archived |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 01 | 52541 | 02.02.2024 | 0 |
| 03 | 01 | 65471 | 03.03.2018 | 0 |
| 06 | 03 | 65464 | 02.02.2024 | 0 |
| 07 | 03 | 46486 | 04.04.2019 | 0 |

From that result, a total of the number of registrations for each company would be useful

| Company_id | TOTAL_rec |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | 2 |
| 03 | 2 |

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Shouldn't row with `ID = 05` be included in _rezults_? Its `archived` is 0 (zero) and its `Date_Rec` is older than 2020.

Comment: no, because Data_rec is not 02.02.2024 for no record of id_company=03

Comment: Why ID=5 is not included? Asking again, because answer is not clear.

Comment: because first where condition is Data_rec = 02.02.2024, records.id=05 it has Data_rec=02.02.2017

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want to build your query in 2 steps:

- Step 1: Select company ids where the date is `02.02.2024`

  ```sql
    SELECT *
    FROM Records
    WHERE Date_Rec = '02.02.2024'
  ```
- Step 2: Use the above query as a subquery in what will get you the record count:

  ```sql
  SELECT Company_id, COUNT(*)
  FROM Records R
  WHERE EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
      FROM Records
      WHERE Date_Rec = '02.02.2024'
      AND Company_id = R.Company_id
  )
  AND archived = 0
  GROUP BY Company_id
  ```

  Or an alternative using an `INNER JOIN`:

  ```sql
  SELECT R1.Company_id, COUNT(*)
  FROM Records R1
  JOIN (
      SELECT *
      FROM Records
      WHERE Date_Rec = '02.02.2024'
  ) R2 ON R1.Company_ID = R2.Company_ID
  WHERE archived = 0
  GROUP BY R1.Company_id
  ```

Note that you did not specify if `archived = 0` should be applied to step 1. I let you add `AND archived = 0` in the subquery if necessary.

Comment: If it is fine, consider accepting the answer.